# Set up an automated approval workflow

Tags: sharepoint-designer, sharepoint-online, sharepoint-workspace

I have a set of documents which require approval, they are going to be put onto my sharepoint site so that when users log on they simply select the document which is required and an email is sent to the appropriate person for approval.

How can I go about setting this up?  As from my understanding users have to keep uploading their documents to the sharepoint list which contains the workflow.

An ideal example would be:

The document 'Database approval form' is already in my library.
1) The user goes onto my sharepoint site and selects the document. 
2) An email is sent to management for approval.
3) Management approves.
4) Workflow complete.

Notice that there is no need for the user to upload the 'Database approval form' to the library, as it already exisits.

Any help is much apprechiated.

Thanks,
Sandeep

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you correctly, you can create a simple sharepoint designer workflow and publish that on your site.

Comment: I can set the workflow up, but that would mean users will have to upload their documents to the site in order to use the workflow each time. I'm trying to have it set up so that the documents are already in the library, so that users can simply log on, find their document in my library and launch the workflow.

Comment: Just publish the workflow and ask you users to manually launch the workflow for the workflow.

Comment: Is there anyway to automate the lauching of the workflow ?

Comment: You can add a column called "start workflow" and in your workflow check if this field is checked then start the workflow